# Message passing between unopened webpage and Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

New to developing Chrome extensions but would like to know if it's possible for a chrome extension to receive data from a web page that the current user does not have open. I.e. scrape data from any given website

For example, if a user only has their homepage open, but "http://mydomain.page.html" changes its page contents from:
"It is 5 pm" 
to 
"It is 6 pm.", 
is there a way to indicate the user of this change via Chrome extension? 
I've come across plenty of somewhat similar examples but they all seem to deal with a chrome extension only talking to a page the user currently has open in a tab or another window. 
I've looked up [Long Lived Connections](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) but not sure if that totally applies.

Comment: What do you mean by unopened? Is it inactive tab?

Comment: I've made a few edits to the question but no, not an inactive tab. I just want to pull data from an external source on the web that I'm hosting - webpage or not.

Comment: Simply download the URL with XHR/fetch and parse it via DOMParser.

Comment: Thanks - any code you could post as a guide would be helpful